# short call for singleton

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, singleton, dry

**Update with working code. Problem was like @HotLinks state, that I did `init` instead of `initWithBaseURL:url`**

I am using a `Singleton` in my App, based on [this guide](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/).

Now every time I use the singleton I do like this:

```
SingletonClass* sharedSingleton = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];
[sharedSingleton callAMethod];

// or 

[[SingletonClass sharedInstance] callAMethod];
```

**Is there a way to use a short syntax, especially if I have to use the `Singleton` several times?** Something like:

```
[sc callAMethod];
```

I tried already this kind, but it did not work, as the init method was not called...

#### WebApi.h

```c
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
#import "SingletonClass.h"

@interface WebApi : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

@property (nonatomic, strong) SingletonClass *sc;

+(WebApi*)sharedInstance;

-(void)sandbox;

@end
```

#### WebApi.m (updated with working code)

```c
#import "WebApi.h"

@implementation WebApi

//-(WebApi*)init {
-(WebApi*)initWithBaseURL:url {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.sc = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];  // is never called.
    }
    return  self;
}

#pragma mark - Singleton methods
/**
 * Singleton methods
 */
+(WebApi*)sharedInstance
{
    static WebApi *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kApiHost]];
    });        
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)sandbox {
 DLog(@"test short singleton call: %@", [sc callAMethod]; 
}
@end
```

#### Debug Message

> [WebApi sandbox] [Line 42] test short singleton call: (null)

Comment: You can certainly create a "class" ("+") method of your singleton class that obtains the singleton pointer and then cascades to the instance method.

Comment: What about just: `#define SC [SingletonClass sharedInstance]`

Comment: @HotLicks I often have recognized that init methods where not called - at least breakpoints where never hit, that where placed on the init method. It was always strange to me, but I could never figure out why.

Yes I am calling it in another Singleton class.

Comment: And you can use the code you have above, only in a client class rather than the singleton class.  The above code isn't working both because your init method is never called and because, if you got it named right, you'd be accessing the singleton pointer before it was set.

Comment: `init` is not called because you're calling `initWithBaseURL`.

Comment: @HotLicks `ìnitWithBaseURL` did the trick. Now its working!

Comment: @JamesWebster `#define` did not work. I get semnatic issue warnings

Comment: If you're going to implement initWithBaseURL you need to cascade your super call to that method rather than init.

Comment: You realize, of course, that in `sandbox` you could just call `[self callAMethod]`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can do this in any language. In Java, you would generally see

```
<Class>.getInstance().<blah>.
```

There's nothing stopping you from getting that instance inside a method where it will be used a lot, e.g.

```
WebApi *api = [WebApi sharedInstance];
```

then a whole lot of:

```
[api <method1>];
...
```

Does that get you there?

(Amusingly, a developer and I were discussing this issue yesterday because the example code Apple has for use of the accelerometer puts the motion manager in the app delegate and the syntax to get a hold of the manager is completely insane:

```
CMMotionManager *mManager = [(APLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];
```

As you can see, they are making a local var and then diddling that from there on in the controller class.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a global variable and set it in your `+sharedInstance` method, then make sure you call `+sharedInstance` once.

But, really, don't bother.   Using `[SomeClass sharedInstance]` makes it easy to quantify all uses of shared instances in your code base, as well as all uses of `SomeClass`'s class level API.   Both  are quite useful for anyone else that ends up maintaining your code.

Secondly, it doesn't really save *that* much typing.  Not enough to justify requiring everyone to learn about a new global.

---

(What Rob said):

Finally, if you are calling instance methods on the shared instance repeatedly in a scope, just use a local variable:

```
ThingManager *thingManager = [ThingManager sharedInstance];
[thingManager foo];
[thingManager bar];
[thingManager baz];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

In .h file

```
@interface WebApi : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

@property (nonatomic, strong) SingletonClass *sc;
...
+(id) methodName;
...
@end
```

In .m file

```
+(id) methodName
{
    return [[WebApi shareInstance] instanceMethod];
}

- (id) instanceMethod
{
     return @"SMTH";
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to do this instead of the solution in my post?